# Sine Law or No?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, contest-math, triangles

The diagram shows a triangle $ABC$ where 
$$AB = AC,\, BC = AD \text{ and } \angle BAC = 20°.$$
Find $\angle ADB$.

[image]

I used the Sine Law; We know that $\sin(C)/\sin(BDC) = \sin(A)/\sin(ABD)$ If we let $\sin BDC = a$, then the equation will be equal to $\sin 80/\sin a = \sin20/\sin(a-20)$, I could not find any correlation with the the angle a and the other angles, is there a way to solve this using the sine law or is it a bad approach in general (or is the implementation of the sine law wrong?).  What other approach would be a lot more useful in this kind of problem?

Comment: Hmm.. I saw a way to get 4 linear equations with 4 variables but every time I try to solve them I just get circular dependencies for some reason.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that SIMOC is not currently active, so this isn't a contest problem that shouldn't be posted.  Or, even better, this is from the 2015 SIMOC and has a final answer posted already anyway.

Comment: Link to the contest: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0-8qjwNLbpgTGxJclpsNjhZUFU/view , btw the answer is 150 degrees ;Dj

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Oh I am Very sorry the edit messed up as it did not show the question (thanks for the edit though) But I am Finding Angle ADB,

Comment: This seems difficult for someone in grade 7. This is from the grade 7 level SASMO 2017 question 10. Would someone in grade 7 know these trig identities? It doesnt seem common anywhere to be taught trigonometry in grade 7. Looking at the solutions here, it looks like it requires quite a lot of creativity and experimenting without the use of trigonometry.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, let start with your equation 
$$\frac{\sin 80}{\sin a}=\frac{\sin 20}{\sin(a-20)}. $$
Using twice equation $\sin(2x)=2\sin x\cos x $, we reach
$$\frac{4\sin 20\cos 20\cos 40 }{\sin a}=\frac{\sin 20}{\sin(a-20)} $$
or
$$\frac{4\cos 20\cos 40}{\sin a}=\frac{1}{\sin(a-20)}. $$
We know that $2\cos20\cos40=\cos60+\cos20 $, thus
$$\frac{1+2\cos 20}{\sin a}=\frac{1}{\sin(a-20)}. $$
Simplifying,
$$\sin a=\sin(a-20)+2\cos20\sin(a-20)=\sin(a-20)+\sin a+\sin(a-40) $$
which turns to
$$\sin(a-20)+\sin(a-40)=0. $$
This equation has $a=30$ as a solution, thus $\sphericalangle BDA=150 $.

Comment: Is there a solution where in it does not involve the sum-product identity, just the basic trig? Or do we really have to  use it in order to answer this question?

Comment: I really have no idea. In solving this question, I tried to use cosine law which was almost work but I didn't go on.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it without any trig at all, but it requires some "inspired" additional constructions. Reflect the triangle across one of its sides, $AC$, and also let $BL$ be the angle bisector of $\angle ABC$:
[image]

All the labelled angles in the diagram are easy to calculate using properties of isosceles triangles and/or sums of angles in triangles, using the reflection symmetry and/or the bisector. For example, $\angle ABK = 70^\circ$ because $\Delta ABK$ is isosceles with vertex $\angle BAK = 40^\circ$.

Now consider $\Delta KLM$ and $\Delta KLC$ - they are congruent by two angles and a side ($KL$ which they have in common), therefore $KM = KC = BC = AD$ (the blue segments; the second equality holds because of the reflection). Also, now we can see $BM = AM = CD$ (the first from the isosceles $\Delta ABM$; the second, from $AD + DC = AC = AB = AK = AM + MK$).

Finally, see that $\Delta BCD$ and $\Delta KMB$ have two sides equal (the blue and red segments) and the $80^\circ$ angle between them as well, so they are congruent, too. From this, $\angle BDC = \angle KBM = 30^\circ$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative construction and demonstration with simple Euclidean geometry below. Sorry for the label change.
[image]
Here we have $AC \cong BC$, $CP \cong AB$ and $\angle ACB = 20°$.

- Draw two isosceles triangles congruent to $ABC$ and with one side in common, so that $\triangle ABC \cong \triangle BCD \cong \triangle DCE$.
- Show that $\triangle ACE$ is equilateral.
- Determine $\angle EAB = \angle CAB - \angle CAE$.
- Demonstrate that $\triangle CPB \cong \triangle EAB$, with SAS criterion. Therefore $\angle CPB \cong \angle ABE$.
- Show that $\triangle DBE$ is isosceles.
- Thus calculate the measure of the angle $\angle DBE = \frac{180°-80°}{2}$.
- So finally $\angle CPB = \angle ABE = \angle ABD - \angle ABE = 150°$.

---

An even simpler construction is reported below ($\triangle ADB$ is equilater; show then that $\triangle ADC \cong \triangle CDB \cong \triangle CPB$ and deduce from there the result).
[image]

Comment: If you dont mind helping me out here, I am lost on this question without trigonometry. If you can answer a few questions. How did you think to do that? Did it take you long to figure out that construction? What made you think this would work? What thought process did you have in deciding I should draw these extra lines and it should reveal the answer to me? Is there a method to what you just did or is it just creativity? Can you recommend a book which you learned geometry from?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Construct equilateral triangle $ADE$ outside triangle $ABC$. Since $AE = AD = BC$ and $$\angle \, EAC = \angle \, EAD + \angle \, BAC = 60^{\circ} + 20^{\circ} = 80^{\circ} = \angle \, BCA$$ triangles $CEA$ and $ABC$ are congruent. However, $ABC$ is isosceles so $CEA$ is also isosceles where $CA = CE$ and $\angle \, ACE =\angle \, CAB = 20^{\circ}$. Moreover, by construction $AD = ED$ and $CD$ is a common side, so the two triangles $\Delta \, ACD$ and $\Delta \, ECD$ are congruent (in fact mirror symmetric with respect to the line $CD$). Hence $\angle\, ACD = \angle \,ECD = \frac{1}{2} \, \angle \, ACE = \frac{1}{2} \, 20^{\circ} = 10^{\circ}.$ Therefore   $$\angle \, ADC = 180^{\circ} - \angle \, CAD - \angle \, DCA = 180^{\circ} - 20^{\circ} - 10^{\circ} = 150^{\circ}$$

Comment: How did you think to do this? What made you want to draw these extra lines? How did you know this would work or was this found through trial and error? Is there some strategy and methodology to what you did? It would be very helpful to me if you can explain how you came up with this construction. It just seems so random to me. Thank you.

Comment: @KayBei There is no strategy or methodology. It comes with developed intuition based on experience together with being able to see and make analogies with theorems and other problems and noteworthy properties. So it requires good command of the knowledge in synthetic geometry.

Comment: thank you. How can someone develop this intuition or gain this experience from home? Do you have books that you can recommend which would show someone how to think in this way, like a mathematician, that have personally shaped the way you think? Do you know of any good books in mathematical reasoning/problem solving that influenced you? Any good synthetic geometry books? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @KayBei In terms of synthetic geometry I solved a lot of geometry problems starting from junior high and high school and I took part in math competitions.,In general solving non-trivial problems in any type of math is a creative process and rarely algorithmic (even the creation of algorithmic methodologies is a creative process itself). To develop intuition, skill and knowledge to draw upon, you have to follow lectures,practice alongside tutorials, solve and see solutions of a lot of problems, prattice applications of mathematical models, listen to talks given by other mathematicians, read.

Comment: Thanks @Futurologist . I don’t know which books to read for practicing problem solving. A problem book you can recommend?