# Find $x$ angle in triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I need to find angle `x` in this isosceles triangle(20-80-80), by using pure geometry, if i can say so. If my calculations are correct (i tried another approach) answer should be `30`, but there should be 'easy' way to find this.
Also i found many [Langley’s Adventitious Angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langley%E2%80%99s_Adventitious_Angles) exercises which are very similar to mine but yet different.

[image]

Comment: thats trigonometry solution. not what im looking for

Comment: @Blue The solution in the linked topic by trigonometry only, because the topic starter looked for trigonometric solution only. I think we need to open this topic.

Comment: Note: A trigonometric solution is offered in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3079148/in-triangle-abc-with-ab-ac-and-angle-bac-20-circ-d-is-on-ac-with).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3126628/480425. Here I propose a couple of nice solutions using simple Euclidean geometry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In $\triangle ABC$ with $AB=AC$ and $\angle BAC=20^\circ$, $D$ is on $AC$, with $BC=AD$. Find $\angle DBC$. Where's my error?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3079148/in-triangle-abc-with-ab-ac-and-angle-bac-20-circ-d-is-on-ac-with)

Comment: @Aretino See please my previous comment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Construct an equilateral triangle such that its sides are equal to the base of the main triangle.
[image]

Comment: Well, both your's solution are beatifull and I can not upvote both if you write them in the same answer.

Comment: @greedoid,  you mean I have to post them as two different answers? I am not really familiar with the voting rules.

Comment: Yes, that is correct if you want another upvote.

Comment: @greedoid, Thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 7):

And my second solution is as follow:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Let in $\Delta ABC$ we have $AB=AC$, $\measuredangle A=20^{\circ}$ and $\measuredangle ADC=x$ as on your picture.

Let $M\in AB$ such that $AD=MD$ and $K\in DC$ such that $MK=AD$.

Also, let $B'\in MB$ such that $MB'=AD$ and $C'\in KC$ such that $B'C'||BC.$

Thus, $$\measuredangle MKA=\measuredangle MDK=2\cdot20^{\circ}=40^{\circ}$$ and from here
$$\measuredangle B'MK=40^{\circ}+20^{\circ}=60^{\circ},$$ which says $$B'K=MB'=AD=BC.$$
But $$\measuredangle B'KC'=60^{\circ}+20^{\circ}=80^{\circ}=\measuredangle BCA=\measuredangle B'C'A.$$

Thus, $$B'C'=B'K=AD=BC,$$ which says that
$$B\equiv B'$$ and $$C\equiv C'.$$
Id est, 
 $$\measuredangle BDC=10^{\circ}+20^{\circ}=30^{\circ}.$$

Comment: Nice as always +1

Answer (score 5):

[image]

construct triangle $\Delta BCE$ congruent to $\Delta ADB$.

so $AB = BE$, $\angle ABE = 80° - 20°  = 60°$

Thus triangle $\Delta ABE$ is equilateral.

$AB = AE = AC$, since $\angle CAE = 60° - 20° =40°$

$\angle AEC = \frac{180° - 40°}{2} = 70°$

so $x = 20° + \angle ABD = 20° + \angle CBE = 20°  + (70° - 60° ) = 30°$

Comment: Very nice +1......